# Request: Person must give reason for downvote

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Asking effective questions is more of an art than a science.

I request new function - person must give reason for downvoting question

For instance, I believe [my question is clear](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/81516/in-what-order-to-practice-holding-notes-on-bansuri), yet someone is downvoting. Does person have genuine reason, and can they offer critique for improvement, or is it some online troll.

Comment: Related on Meta SO: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436) (and their linked questions) or on Meta SE: [Mandatory comment after downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215422) (and their linked questions)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Meta.SE, not Music Meta. And by the way, as commenters have mentioned, it already is on that site, so it's a dupe anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Marium, as per @Andrew T's comment

> Related on Meta SO: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436) (and their linked questions) or on Meta SE: [Mandatory comment after downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215422) (and their linked questions)

There is no appetite on Stack Exchange to mandate this. If there is no comment, you can generally assume the tooltip reason:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

But in any case, anybody in the community can upvote or downvote as they wish. That is one of the key permissions here.

As per your specific question you linked to, it is not structured that well - you ask for something that could be opinion based. Some may practice it one way, others another way.